# C# Deleting Files - IOException handling

Tags: c#

In reference to [Deleting All Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954708/delete-all-files-and-folders-in-multiple-directory-but-leave-the-directoy) how can we handle IO.Exceptions to quietly "skip" those files that the delete can't do? Should we use a try/catch or is there something built-in?

Looks like a simple question but I'm actually having trouble finding a solution for it on the net...

Comment: The only way you can deal with an exception *is* to catch it.

Comment: You can refer to this StackOverFlow post very similar to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329355/cannot-delete-directory-with-directory-deletepath-true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
       public void DeleteDirectoryFiles(DirectoryInfo dirInfo) 
              {
                  foreach(FileInfo files in dirInfo.GetFiles()) 
                      {
                         try
                            {
                            files.Delete(); 
                            }
                         catch(IOException ex)
                            {
                                  // code to handle
                            }
                      }

              }
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course. To update the code from the [original answer by John Hartsock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2954759/993547):

```
public void DeleteDirectoryFolders(DirectoryInfo dirInfo, bool ignoreIfFailed = false){
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dirs in dirInfo.GetDirectories()) 
    {
        try
        {
            dirs.Delete(true); 
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            if (!ignoreIfFailed)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    } 
}

public void DeleteDirectoryFiles(DirectoryInfo dirInfo, bool ignoreIfFailed = false) {
    foreach(FileInfo files in dirInfo.GetFiles()) 
    { 
        try
        {
            files.Delete(); 
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            if (!ignoreIfFailed)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    } 
}

public void DeleteDirectoryFilesAndFolders(string dirName, bool ignoreIfFailed = false) {
  DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirName); 
  DeleteDirectoryFiles(dir, ignoreIfFailed);
  DeleteDirectoryFolders(dir, ignoreIfFailed);
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
DeleteDirectoryFilesAndFolders(folder, true); // ignore on error

DeleteDirectoryFilesAndFolders(folder, false); // throw exception

DeleteDirectoryFilesAndFolders(folder); // throw exception
```

Comment: @lloydom did you mean to post that to the question instead of to this answer?

Comment: yup sorry will remove it from here

Answer (score 0):

The only way to handle an exception quietly would be a `try catch` with nothing in the `catch` block.

Be sure to only catch the exception you're expecting though (i.e., `catch (IOException)`) else you might mask some other problem that you weren't aware of.